# I can't reinstall the program after I remove it

Tags: windows

I have a program called Gaussian 09 for quantum computation. I tried once to remove and reinstall it again but the installation window doesn't show up. I tried a lot of things but no benefit so I format my pc and install it. now the same problem happens again and I don't want to format my computer. is there any other way?

the issue details: when I run the setup.exe file it asks me for permission and then doesn't do anything but it is shown in task manager enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7l0L.png)

Comment: Gaussian 09 is commercial software. Do you have a proper license key?

Comment: yes, I do. and I install it correctly before. The problem appears when I remove and reinstall it again

Comment: Thank you. I would contact the software vendor for assistance on this issue.